# running metabat2 with snakemake but not getting the bin files

Tags: snakemake

I have been trying to run metabat2 with snakemake. I can run it but the output files in metabat2/ are missing. The checkM that works after it does use the data and can work I just cant find the files later. There should be files created with numbers but it is imposible to predict how many files will be created. Is there a way I can specify it to make sure that the files are created in that file?

```
rule all:
    [f"metabat2/" for sample in samples],
    [f"checkm/" for sample in samples]
rule metabat2:
    input:
        "input/consensus.fasta"
    output:
        directory("metabat2/")
    conda:
        "envs/metabat2.yaml"
    shell:
        "metabat2 -i {input} -o {output} -v"

rule checkM:
    input:
        "metabat2/"
    output:
        c = "bacteria/CheckM.txt",
    d = directory("checkm/")
    conda:
        "envs/metabat2.yaml"
    shell:
        "checkm lineage_wf -f {output.c} -t 10 -x fa {input} {output.d}"
```

the normal code to run metabat2 would be

```
 metabat2 -i path/to/consensus.fasta -o /outputdir/bin -v
```

this will create in outputdir files with bin.[number].fa

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell what the problem is but I have a couple of suggestions...

- `[f"metabat2/" for sample in samples]`: I doubt this will do what you expect as it will simply create a list with the string `metabat2/` repeat `len(samples)` times. Maybe you want `[f"metabat2/{sample}" for sample in samples]`? The same for `[f"checkm/" for sample in samples]`
- The `samples` variable is not used anywhere in the rules following `all`. I suspect somewhere it should be used and/or you should use something like `output: directory("metabat2/{sample}")`
- Execute snakemake with `-p` option to see what commands are executed. It may be useful to post the stdout from it.

Comment: Hi dariober the problem is that I have an unpredictable amount of output files and I would like to create those and then put those files into a new tool but I cant make it work. I have removed the for sample in samples because I dont need that in there that was from a previous run.